# Quick question about "shifting x axis"

Tags: plotting, astronomy

Imagine I have two lists:

```
x={x1,x2,x3,x4,...}
y={y1,y2,y3,y4,...}
```

And I want a listplot

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x,y}]]
```

Would do the job. What can I do if I want a plot with the order of the x axis shifted? Something like: instead of the latter code, it'd read

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{-x,y}]]
```

This comes from [HR diagrams](https://www.eso.org/public/chile/images/eso0728c/?lang), in where Temperature decreases as "the x axis grows".

Specifically, I have this plot:

[image: rough HR diagram attempt]

And I'd like to invert $\log T$ from $~4.4$ to $~3.5$

The code is

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{temp, lum}], PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Green}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperatura Log T [K]", FontSize -> 22, Bold], 
   Style["Luminosidad Log L [\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(sol\)]\)]", 
    FontSize -> 22, Bold]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{temp//Reverse, lum}]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}];

ListLinePlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}]
```

[image]